client_secret is missing for Integrating Google sign in for macOS
I am trying to integrate Google Signin for macOS. I created a native macOS app with Swift and AppKit Cocoa
In my info.plist I added below code
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.MY_IDENTIFIER</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>GIDClientID</key>
    <string>MY_IDENTIFIER.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>
    <key>GIDServerClientID</key>
    <string>MY_IDENTIFIER_TWO.apps.googleusercontent.com</string>

My swift code on button click for Google SignIn
@objc func button1Clicked() {
        if let window = view.window {
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: window) { signInResult, error in
                debugPrint("Error \(error)")
                guard error == nil else { return }
                guard let signInResult = signInResult else { return }
                let user = signInResult.user
                let emailAddress = user.profile?.email
                let fullName = user.profile?.name
                let givenName = user.profile?.givenName
                let familyName = user.profile?.familyName
                let profilePicUrl = user.profile?.imageURL(withDimension: 320)
                
                
                // If sign in succeeded, display the app's main content View.
            }
        }
        
        
    }

I get error saying
"Error Optional(Error Domain=org.openid.appauth.oauth_token Code=-2 \"invalid_request: client_secret is missing.\" UserInfo={OIDOAuthErrorResponseErrorKey={\n    error = \"invalid_request\";\n    \"error_description\" = \"client_secret is missing.\";\n}, NSLocalizedDescription=invalid_request: client_secret is missing., NSUnderlyingError=0x600002973660 {Error Domain=org.openid.appauth.remote-http Code=400 \"{\n  \"error\": \"invalid_request\",\n  \"error_description\": \"client_secret is missing.\"\n}\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription={\n  \"error\": \"invalid_request\",\n  \"error_description\": \"client_secret is missing.\"\n}}}})"
I have also created Client ID for Web Application

Client ID for Desktop


I used Client ID for ios type in my flutter app for macos and it worked.
